# Direct link to resource file in class library

Tags: c#, .net, dll

I have got file.xml in my class library solution and in a class I access to it like this:

```
var xmlFile = "file.xml"
```

Is possible to put there any path to build-embedded file.xml so if I use dll later I don't need to load that file.xml as a resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, embedded resources are not accessible directly through a path; you need to load them manuallty.